# Pros and cons of the idea of parallell data transmission

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, internet, udp, transport-protocol

I am learning the basics of internet protocols and related principles. I recently performed experiments comparing UDP and TCP. But when I did that (using the ttcp program) it was only one process and only one port. IIUC we could not parallelize on the same port, but could we increase "efficiency" (throughput or even total data sent) by sending several transmissions at several ports using several processes in parallel? Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a single link out of the host, then your data is only sent serially, so splitting the data stream into "parallel" streams really does nothing but buffer multiple streams contending for the interface instead of one stream queuing up on the interface.

On the other hand, if you have multiple paths from your host, splitting a data stream into multiple streams can cause out-of-order packet delivery, which can be handled by TCP, but at a performance cost to reorder the data before giving it to the application on the other end, but UDP will not reorder the out-of-order data before delivering it to the application, so that must be handled by the application protocol, and it can be death to real-time protocols like VoIP or video, where late data is useless and must be discarded.

There are cases of parallel streams seem to be more efficient, such as HTTP splitting page requests into different streams for different page elements to make it appear that the various parts of the page load simultaneously. It is not really more efficient because everything is serialized, albeit interleaved, but it is more visually appealing.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a single link out of the host, then your data is only sent
> serially, so splitting the data stream into "parallel" streams really
> does nothing but buffer multiple streams contending for the interface
> instead of one stream queuing up on the interface.

The above statement makes sense logically.  And while that can often be the case, there's another factor to consider.

Sent data packets are not guaranteed to arrive at the intended recipient without the possibility of getting lost, delayed, mis-ordered or corrupted. The TCP layer provides a guarantee that the data will either get delivered correctly or at least it will notify you that it failed trying everything it could.

In order to accomplish this, the sender sends some data and waits for the receiver to confirm that it was received correctly before sending more.  If it fails to get confirmation within a certain amount of time or gets notice that it was received incorrectly, it can retry sending the same data over again a certain number of times until it gets confirmation that all is well. This wait for confirmation before continuing also keeps the sender from sending data faster than a receiver might be capable of handling the incoming data.   In order to optimize data transmission under various conditions, a number of complex algorithms are used to dynamically agree upon and continually adjust the amount of data that can be sent between acknowledgements, the length of time to  wait for acknowledgement, etc.

It is this waiting time between acknowledgements that's key to understanding why multiple parallel streams of data can sometimes perform better than a single stream even when they have to share the same single link.

When the the network is fast, congestion, error and dropout free and the endpoints are "close" to each other, the  round trip of transmission and acknowledgement is very short and little to no time is spent waiting for acknowledgements. The network link is kept busy with active data transfer and parallelizing it doesn't help much if any.

However consider if the other endpoint is far away on a busy network that takes comparatively much longer for a data packet to travel from one endpoint to another.   There will be periods of inactivity where the sender can't send because it's waiting on the acknowledgement message to come back before sending more and the network link is sitting idle for part of the time.

One way to improve the throughput in this case is to start several parallel conversations. They will randomly end up being in different parts of the sending/acknowledging/waiting cycles.  While conversation A is stuck waiting, conversation B can be using the link for sending, and maybe conversation C is sending while both B and A are waiting and so forth.

This has its limits as eventually they start competing with each other when multiple conversations are ready to send data at once. The optimal number of parallel streams will vary by circumstance.   In cases where it is helpful to parallelize, adding the first few will usually add the largest benefit, with diminishing returns with each addition after that.    There are other limits, including available CPU, memory and disk throughput.

Typically it is too complicated programming-wise for a single application to keep track of multiple parallel streams of data that are supposed to represent a single file, etc and try to figure out how to split up this data into parallel streams and then recombine it later.

Often the easiest approach to parallel data transfer comes when you have many smaller files to move and each can be moved by a single file transfer program.   For example: suppose you have 30 approximately equal sized files to move:  Three instances of a file transfer program can be run at the same time with the first one responsible for files 00-09, the second 10-19, and the third 20-29.

In addition to moving data more optimally over a slow network, there are other benefits.  If additional processing work needs to be done on the data stream at each end, such as encryption/decryption for security, multiple CPU processing cores (now commonplace on most computers) can be utilized to work on multiple streams.  Where with sending everything sequentially, typically only one CPU core is able to do the work.

Comment: You seem to entirely miss the point of TCP's *sliding* window...

Comment: @Zac67 - the sliding window is indirectly referenced in "a number of complex algorithms are used to dynamically..."   and it is primarily concerned with the size of the receiver's buffer and not congestion, latency, dropped packets although those influence it.  There are other algorithms that help with those issues but they can't always fully optimize things for a single stream under less than ideal conditions.  That's why high performance transfer protocols for large file transfers such as [GridFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GridFTP) make use of parallel data streams.

Comment: * it is primarily concerned with the size of the receiver's buffer and not congestion* - actually, TCP congestion control uses the window size to control the effective bandwidth.

Comment: @Zac67, there's actually a "congestion window" (sender side managed) which is different from the "sliding window" (destination side managed)  Its job is to make your traffic a good network citizen and reduce your bandwidth in cases of congestion.  Its aim is not to maximize your bandwidth.